# Rails Find DISTINCT records with Lowest price

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I Have a Model

Model-1 having fields

- Number Price
- Price

Number can be same.
I want to show All Model-1 record but if there is Two or More records with same number,I want it just show Record having Lowest Price.

How i will write a query in Controller.
Please don't suggest me with conditions in view.

Comment: Am using postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's think about this in SQL.  What would that query look like?

If you want the lowest specific value, then you would create a query that asked for the price, and ordered by the number, then price.

```
SELECT *
FROM model-1
WHERE number = :number
ORDER BY number ASC, price ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

This will ensure that the order of your entries are first ordered by the number, then by the lowest price (ASC is ascending order, so from 1 to 10).  You then only get the one element you care about.

In Rails, if you're using ActiveRecord, then that may look like this.

```
model = Model1.find_by(number: 123).order('number ASC, price ASC').limit(1)
```

Comment: Thaks for your helping.
Please see my Edited Question. i Hope you will help me.

Comment: I'm going to revert that edit, since that is a fundamental change in your question and thus invalidates this answer.  If you have a different question, please ask a different question.